# Implications of IP change on boot node?

Tags: private-blockchain, parity, bootnodes

I have a private blockchain using Parity.  One of the bootnodes may have to change the IP.  What is the correct way to do this and what are the implications of this?

This question implies questions like these:

Is it as simple as distributing a new chain specification?

Would this be considered a fork?

What things should I look for and worry about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the correct way to do this and what are the implications of this?

You have to update the IP in the chain spec or in your bootnodes configuration. Otherwise, Parity won't know the route over IP to the node.

> Is it as simple as distributing a new chain specification?

Exactly.

> Would this be considered a fork?

No, this only affects the node configuration, not the chain itself.

> What things should I look for and worry about?

The main pain point would be telling all users to upgrade their nodes. If you change all bootnodes at the same time, they may not find any peers if they do not upgrade their configurations.

Comment: @Wawar_Lim what do you mean "or in your bootnodes configuration"?

Comment: There's a `--bootnodes` configuration flag that overrides the chain specification.